# How do I repeat the button when it is clicked multiple times?

Tags: javascript

For example, when I click 111222, `display` will show 111222.

```
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons){
    numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)
    function showNumber(){
        display.innerHTML = numberButtons.innerHTML
    }
});

<body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="display">0</div>
      <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
      <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` (`x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to append instead:

```
display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML
```

Comment: quick question: how do I remove the '0' once a button is clicked?